# How to use realm with async fetch request?

Tags: react-native, mobile, async-await, realm-js

I have meet this situation for my requirements：

step 1. save data to local db which in the mobile phone (realm)

step 2. upload the local data to the server, and the server will return the data ids if success
step 3. delete the records in local db by the returned ids which get by step2

```
Realm.open({schema:[MySchame],encryptionKey:getRealmKey()})
        .then(realm =>{
            realm.write(() => {
                // 1. get all step data from db
                let objetcs = realm.objects('MySchema');
                // 2. upload obtained data to server
                if(objetcs.length > 0){
                    let recordArr = [];
                    for (let o of steps){
                        recordArr.push(o.get());
                    }
                   uploadDataToServer(recordArr,(res)=>{
                        //3. filter the uploaded steps and delete them
                        let uploadedSteps = realm.objects('MySchema').filtered('id=$0',res.id);
                        if(uploadedSteps.length > 0){
                            realm.delete(uploadedSteps);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
            realm.close();
        })
        .catch(error =>{
            console.log(error);
        });
```

but this is not works as expected, it seems DB is closed too early than networks success callback. 
Thanks for any ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create a service like one below

```js
import repository from "./realmConfig";

let CatalogsService = {
    findAll: function () {
        return repository.objects("CatalogsModel");
    },

    save: function (catalogs) {
        repository.write(() => {
            repository.create("CatalogsModel", catalogs);
        });
    },
    delete: function () {
        repository.write(() => {
            let all = repository.objects("CatalogsModel");
            repository.delete(all);
        });
    },

    update: function (catalogs, callback) {
        if (!callback) return;
        repository.write(() => {
            callback();
            catalogs.updatedAt = new Date();
        });
    }
};

module.exports = CatalogsService;
```

where my `realmConfig` file is as

```js
import Realm from "realm";

class CatalogsModel extends Realm.Object { }
CatalogsModel.schema = {
    name: "CatalogsModel",
    primaryKey: "id",
    properties: {
        id: "string",
        name: "string",
        url: "string",
        status: "int"
    }
};
class OffersModel extends Realm.Object { }
OffersModel.schema = {
    name: "OffersModel",
    primaryKey: "id",
    properties: {
        id: "string",
        name: "string",
        url: "string",
        status: "int",
        machineId: "string",
        machineName: "string"
    }
};

export default new Realm({
    schema: [CatalogsModel, OffersModel],
    schemaVersion: 1,
    deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded: true

});
```

Now import `Service.js` where you are calling `async` server call and do your job. For reference see below code

```js
import CatalogService from './path/to/CatalogService .js'

//get objects
var catalogs = CatalogsService.findAll();

// fire async function , I prefer axios for network calls

Axios.post("SERVER_URL", {
        data: catalogs
    })
    .then(function (response) {
        if (response.success)
            CatalogsService.delete()
    }
```

I assume you can easily modify `findAll()` and `delete()` method as per your need

Comment: don't you need close the DB after use it? And if I have more than one schema, so what export my realm config? each time with `New Realm`?

Comment: for more than one schema I have edited the code above. As it's just  a example you may close the db on Exit of your application

Answer (score 1):

Finally ,I use realm like this:

```
let realm = new Realm({schema:[JOB_SCHEMA.jobTrack],encryptionKey:getRealmKey()});
        let objects = realm.objects('JobTrack');
        realm.beginTransaction();
        realm.delete(objects);
        realm.commitTransaction();
        realm.close();
```

Comment: This helped me! Thank you. 

May i ask if there would be any memory issues when creating a new instance of Realm every time you query?

Comment: hi Delice,  there no need to create new instance , it just an example